# Preserve the last keyframe property in CSS animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a div with some text:

```
<div>Rain.js</div>
```

and its CSS:

```
div {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  color:black;
  font-size:70px;
}
```

I want to make the `div` fade in so I made an animation `fadein` to change the `opacity` of the `div` from 0 to 0.1

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.1; }
}
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qm3f6717/1/) the `fadein` from `opacity` 0 to 0.1 occurs in 2 seconds as expected. But after 2 seconds the opacity goes from 0.1 to 1.

1) Why does this happen?

2) How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not added [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to preserve the final state of the animation.

Since there are no default properties set for opacity in your CSS rules and the `animation-fill-mode` by default is none, the element takes the default opacity value of 1 after the animation is finished.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qm3f6717/4/)

```css
div {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  color: black;
  font-size: 70px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Rain.js</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @m4n0 ! animation-fill-mode was what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

When the animation ends it puts the `div` in his `opacity` default state, which is not set. (therefore it will be `1`).

Add to your CSS on the `div`:

`opacity: 0.1;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3f6717/1/

Answer (score 1):

After the fadein is done, the div takes on its specified values.

You simply need to make the opacity of the div equal to the final key frame opacity value.

```
div
{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    color:black;
    font-size:70px;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```